# How to validate that number of rows in the table should match the number of additions performed By Clicking ADD button?

Tags: python, selenium, datatables, robotframework, selenium2library

How to validate that number of rows in the table should match the number of additions performed By  Clicking **ADD** button?

Initially it will be like this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVEK5.png)

Now, need to add some data as rows of this table..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4480.png)

Now, rows added..
how can I validate that how many rows are added by clicking **ADD** button.

Thank you..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

${Length}                  |        get element count    |     {Locator}

Log To Console             |        ${Length}

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("[your_webpage]")
```

Next, you need to tell Selenium the xPath of this specific table element.

```
l = driver.find_elements_by_xpath ("//*[@class= 'spTable']/tbody/tr")

print (len(l))
```